# Trying to keep an Excel Solver model linear

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I trying to use the solver add-in to optimize production levels for 14 different value streams over the next three months.  I'm looking for a build plan that produces the minimal amount of backlog.  My model calculates the difference in capacity and demand for each value stream, each month.  For my objective I used =SUMIF(E24:R26,"<0").  I want that value as close to 0 as possible.  Using that formula though won't let me use the linear method.  I would prefer to use the linear method, so I can get the global optimum solution, instead of a local optimum solution with the non-linear methods.  Is there a way to sum only the negative values, and still keep it linear?